# The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

Estou tentando criar um método para salva usuários no banco de dados, fazendo a seguinte verificação caso o `id` do usuário passado seja diferente de `null` ele altera se não ele cadastra.

#### Código

```
    public void salvar(Usuario usuario){
    if(usuario.getIdUsuario() != null){ //erro aqui
        aleterar(usuario);
    }else {
        cadastrar(usuario);
    }
}
```

**Erro**

> The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) type int, null

Comment: The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) type int, null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se precisa verificar se o objeto é nulo, verifique só ele, se precisa verificar o resultado, então a verificação deve ser outra, depende do retorno do método usado:

```
public void salvar(Usuario usuario) {
    if (usuario != null) alterar(usuario);
    else cadastrar(usuario);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/NullReferenceValidation.java).

Comment: È isso mesmo, no caso vou cadastra o usuario no banco, caso ele seja nulo, eu cadastro se nao entende-se que o usuario quer aleterar.

Answer (score 7):

Tipos primitivos não podem assumir o valor `null`, só objetos

```
if(usuario.getIdUsuario() != 0){
    aleterar(usuario);
}else {
    cadastrar(usuario);
}
```

Comment: Tinha esquecido desse detalhe , obirgado.